# Beautiful Soup error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить объявления со всем известного сайта. Выделил все блоки объявлений о объект Soup, пытаюсь получить из них описания объявлений в цикле и получаю ошибку.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


HOST = 'https://www.avito.ru'
URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/novorossiysk/noutbuki'
HEADERS = {'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', 
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 YaBrowser/21.6.4.786 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

   
def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_="iva-item-content-UnQQ4") #Все блоки с объявлениями со страницы.
    noutbuki = []
    for item in items:
        noutbuki.append(item.find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text()) # Хочу получить текст описания с объявления.
        
    print(noutbuki)

html = get_html(URL)
get_content(html.text)
```

Если я обращаюсь к нужному мне элементу вот так, по индексу, например первое:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_="iva-item-content-UnQQ4")
item = items[0].find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text() # Нужное мне описания с объявления.
```

то никакой ошибки  не возникает и я получаю нужный текст. Если я пытаюсь сделать это в цикле пробежавшись по items непременно получаю ошибку.
Пробовал сначала сделать item переменной и потом добавить в список - та же ошибка.
Как мне добавить описания объявлений в список в цикле?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые элементы на странице, например, VIP-объявления не имеют блока с описанием. Вы пытаетесь извлечь этот элемент, получаете `None`, который не имеет метода `get_text()`. Вам в коде нужно как-то обрабатывать такие случаи.

```
In [8]: items[0].find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text()
Out[8]: 'Продам ноутбук Acer.\nОтлично подойдёт для игр, учёбы и работы. \nХарактеристики.\nПроцессор: Intel i5\xa0— 5200u.\nОперативная память: 8Gb.\nВидеокарта: Nvidia 940m 2Gb.\nВстроенная графика: Intel HD 5500.\nНакопитель: Ssd 128Gb.\nОперационка: Windows 10.\nНоутбук в хорошем состоянии, готов к любым проверкам. \nИгры\xa0— Танки, Warface, Dota, Csgo идут на высоких настройках. \nПолностью обслужен, почищен от пыли, заменена термопаста. '

In [9]: items[7].find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5d855a4de8ec> in <module>
----> 1 items[7].find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что на каком-то из объявлений попросту нет описания, вы можете дописать `try` и `except`, чтобы ваш код продолжал дальше работать в случае возникновения каких-либо ошибок на момент получения описания с объявления. Что вы будете делать если возникнет ошибка, нужно ли вам объявление без описания или нет - решайте сами.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожей ситуацией,- проблема оказалась в том, что объект пустой.
Решил примитивно:

```html
if item.find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y') is not None:
    noutbuki.append(item.find('div', class_='iva-item-descriptionStep-QGE8Y').get_text())
```